# Database Insert Help?

Tags: c#, mysql, database, visual-studio-2010

Hello I am making a reservation system and I am having troubles with my table can someone help me with my problem. 
I have a table customer and a table reservation. 
My customer table handles all the customers personal info and the reservation handles the reservation details.

My customer table has a customer ID which is a primary key and auto increment. and 
my reservation table has a reservation ID which is a primary key and auto increment.

MY PROBLEM IS... How could I connect the two?

I have a big problem on how to join them in my select statement because I dont know what values will I join.

*Note: Btw, I'm using c# winform and I seperated the add customer and add reservation details. I am also wondering if I can include the 2 insert statement in one button or add them seperately..

Comment: It would do some good to familiarize yourself with Database Normalization, if you aren't already. This will give you a primer on how keys and foreign keys work, and why they are important. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization Knowing how to normalize a DB is the first step to knowing how to denormalize (flatten) it back with SQL Joins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [SQL JOIN statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517.aspx) in your SELECT QUERY:

```
SELECT c.CustomerName, r.ReservationTime
FROM reservation r
JOIN customer c ON r.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
```

**Edit:** It sounds like you are having trouble understanding how to get a newly created CustomerId in order to include it in the Reservation table.  The key here is [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id).  After your insert into Customer, get the value from `LAST_INSERT_ID()` - that is the newly created CustomerId.  You can then use that value when you insert into Reservation. Eg:

```
INSERT INTO Customer (CustomerName)
VALUES ('Joe Schmoe');

INSERT INTO Reservation (ReservationTime, CustomerId)
VALUES ('2011-09-12 18:30:00', LAST_INSERT_ID());
```

Pardon syntax errors - SQL Server is my primary language, if you hadn't gathered that already.

Comment: I get your point. But how would I know what customerID will I put in the reservation table?? How would I know that that reservation has customerID 1? that's my problem T_T

Comment: Take a look at [`@@Identity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx).  After you do your insert into the Customer table, use the `@@Identity` value as the CustomerId in the Reservation table.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Gilly. So how would that exactly look like?

Comment: uhmm. Mister My real problem is inserting the value for the foreign key CustID. Because I don't know what value will I put it. I know that the R.CustID and C.CustID should be equal but I dont know how to make them equal. I dont know where will I get a reference for the value that I will input in r.custId. THANKS!

Comment: MySQL doesn't have @@IDENTITY.  Instead use LAST_INSERT_ID().  I'll update my answer with some detail.

Comment: How Would I do that? Whenever I Query Last_INSERT_ID() mysql says that its an error. how could i specify what table the last inserted will be use? I'm sorry im not really good. please elaborate more...

Comment: I *just* edited my answer with an example half a minute before your comment.  See if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your reservation table should have a customer ID as well.
As I understand you, that's not the case yet.
But it should be like that, because every reservation belongs to a customer.

Then, you can join both tables on the customer ID.

Comment: Sir how would I know what custID has a certain reservation have?

Comment: How does your UI for saving a reservation look like? Your users probably have to select a customer who the reservation is for, right? You need to insert the ID of that customer into the reservation table.

Comment: So. I would Have a combobox with all the customer in my database and the user will choose which customer will have the reservation??

Comment: Sir How Would I connect my combobox to the database so that its values will be connected to the database? that gives me another problem T_T

Comment: You can use data binding for that. I'm no WinForms/databinding guru, so I can't explain it properly. Just search for *winforms combobox databinding* on Google or here on SO.